# Open dialog box in Flutter Stateless widget using ChangeNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, flutter-change-notifier

I have a Stateless flutter widget which shows a list of TODOs. The list is shown using a ChangeNotifierProvider (of TodoList object, which contains a list of todos). Now when I load the page, I want to show a dialog box asking user to enter a new TODO if and only if the existing todos is empty. Inside the builder of the ChangeNotifierProvider, i tried below logic

```
if (todoList.todos.length == 0) {
    _showDialog(context);
    return Column...;
} else {
    return ListBuilder...;
}
```

But its showing 2 dialog box (probably due to the build method executing twice). I have to pass context to dialog box because I'm updating the todoList inside it, which should trigger a rebuild.

How do I handle this scenario. I've tried using flag (_isDialogOpen) but its not still working?

Answer (score 0):

make the widget Stateful in order to use it's lifecycle methods, you can use then `initState()` for showing the dialog when the page widgets are inserted in the widget tree, but you will need to use an `addPostFrameCallback()` to schedule showing it 1 frame after the `initState`'s code gets executed:

First, import:

```
import package:flutter/scheduler.dart.
```

Then use this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  // ...
  SchedulerBinding.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _showDialog(context),);
}
```